# How can I debug and figure out which MFC command is sent in this dump?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

We have a legacy app that is built through MFC frames, and I received a customer dump with a `nullptr` in `_AfxDispatchCmdMsg` in `cmdtarg.cpp`, and I want to figure out what command was actually the problem causing this.

What I know currently:

- The command in the stack dump is a [`WM_COMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command) (since the `nMsg` is `273` which translates to 0x0111 hexa, which is `WM_COMMAND`)
- `WPARAM` is `57603`, meaning the low word is `00000011` (3), and the high word is `11100001` (225)
- `LPARAM` is `0`

I have been reading a lot of MFC docs to understand the mechanisms behind the hood. Haven't coded much in the MFC world, but I wish to learn how to navigate this world better.

For reference, the debug of the command in the stack is:
[image]

I also have two screenshots of the stack, for extra reference

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BwQq.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNiXZ.png

Comment: From the stack it looks like the user did click on the toolbar and the LButtonUp Handler calls your application back which then tries to open a file save dialog which crashes because somehwhere you have forgot to set a non null save file name I guess.

Comment: MFC is this weird "let's try to wrap the Win32 API in classes" thing and `WM_COMMAND` actually comes from Win32. Also if you look at your backtrace, the issue you have there seems no to be the command, but that the program is trying to show a "Save File" dialog with an invalid pointer for the initial file name string. So you have to fix *that* instead of the command being sent. Probably located in either the `CDocument::OnCmdMsg` or the `CView::OnCmdMsg` handler, considering the usual structure of MFC programs.

Comment: looks like it, thanks for the peek.
but if I want to see exactly what command that is (high word 225) how would one go on about reaching it.

Comment: @Loop: Well, it's the command "225". The exact meaning of command numbers is "user" (which in this case means "programmer") defined. You could maybe look through the menu and toolbar resources of the program; each command there as a number.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, seems to be a user command, probably some inter-frame notifications. Are there any keywords that I can use to search through the project to find the command? Both 225, and the hexa version bring no results in visual studio searches.

Comment: @Loop: However be aware that chasing that specific command is approaching the problem from the wrong angle. You must make sure that the paths you pass to file dialogs are valid strings (that is valid pointer, NUL terminated, and ideally also being a valid Win32 path).

Comment: Also, is there a way to actually visualize the UI and frames in visual studio? Right now I am just looking at the code in the dump only.

Comment: Noted. Gonna check the root cause, but I wanted to learn more about commands for general investigations.

Comment: @Loop: Just search through all the `*.rc` files for "225". And if that fails, just search through all your sources for that specific number. Most likely it will translate to some enum or macro token, for which you then do a second search.

Comment: @Loop: Well, the only thing you can actually "visualize" would be dialog resources. There never was a proper "UI" designer for MFC.

Comment: The numeric value of a command is usually assigned to named constant. Start from the .rc file(s), look for `#include`-directives, and search through those header files for the constant 225. By default an MFC project created through the new project wizard uses the filename *resource.h* for symbolic constants.